# I tried to deploy my scipt on PythonAnywhere but got following exception

Tags: pythonanywhere, telethon

I made a script for telegram that changes the avatar every minute when it starts, the following error appears

Attempt 1 at connecting failed: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('149.154.167.51', 443)
Attempt 2 at connecting failed: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('149.154.167.51', 443)
Attempt 3 at connecting failed: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('149.154.167.51', 443)
Attempt 4 at connecting failed: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('149.154.167.51', 443)
Attempt 5 at connecting failed: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('149.154.167.51', 443)
Attempt 6 at connecting failed: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('149.154.167.51', 443)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ainurfast/clocks/main.py", line 13, in 
client.start()
File "/home/ainurfast/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/client/auth.py", line 133, in start
else self.loop.run_until_complete(coro)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
return future.result()
File "/home/ainurfast/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/client/auth.py", line 140, in _start
await self.connect()
File "/home/ainurfast/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/client/telegrambaseclient.py", line 525, in connect
if not await self._sender.connect(self._connection(
File "/home/ainurfast/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/network/mtprotosender.py", line 127, in connect
await self._connect()
File "/home/ainurfast/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/network/mtprotosender.py", line 253, in _connect
raise ConnectionError('Connection to Telegram failed {} time(s)'.format(self._retries))
ConnectionError: Connection to Telegram failed 5 time(s)

> > > 

Answer (score 0):

The mtproto protocol for telegram does not work from a free account on PythonAnywhere. You can use the HTTP protocol or upgrade your account.